# override or overload ToString() in an enum

Tags: c#, enums, overriding, tostring

I have an enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    people1,
    people2
}
```

I want to override or overload ToString() method. For example in the following code, variable `s` becomes "This is people 1".

```
string s=MyEnum.people1.ToString(); //I want s to become "This is people 1"
```

I don't want to create another method with extension method, I want to override or overload `ToString` method.

Comment: You can't override it

Comment: There are a couple of other ways to do it, such as using attributes in which you place the text that you would.

Comment: No in this they are create a method with name GetDescription. I want to override ToString.

Comment: If you want to override it answer is **no you can't**.